# Create Grid view with master page in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, master-pages, connection-string

i am new in asp, i create a grid view with master page. but it show an error in connection string. can anyone help me please?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Smaller" DataKeyNames="Logid" > 
<columns>

          <asp:BoundField DataField="Logid" HeaderText="Logid" SortExpression="Logid" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="PASSWORD" HeaderText="PASSWORD" SortExpression="PASSWORD" />

           <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />

           <asp:BoundField DataField="E_MAIL" HeaderText="E_MAIL" SortExpression="E_MAIL" />

</columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionString:SaqibConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [Logid], [Username], [PASSWORD], [Time_Logged_in], [Time_Logged_Out], [Status], [Date_Logged_in], [E_MAIL]"
UpdateCommand="Update Log_Users SET Logid=@Logid, Username=@Username, PASSWORD=@PASSWORD, Status=@Status, E_mail=@E_mail"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Log_Users WHERE Logid = @Logid">
<UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Logid" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="Username" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="PASSWORD" />
                   <asp:Parameter Name="Status" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="E_MAIL" />

</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: what is the error? And do you have connection string named as 'SaqibConnectionString' in webconfig `connectionStrings` section?

Comment: This is connection strin...connectionString="Data Source=localhost; 
        Initial Catalog=Saqib;
        User Id=sa;
        Password=angel"

Comment: i face error in this line.....<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionString:SaqibConnectionString %>"

Comment: Can you post code of connection string in properly your question?

Comment: <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="db"
      connectionString="Data Source=localhost; 
        Initial Catalog=Sunny;
        User Id=sa;
        Password=xyz" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: You don't have a space between your ID="SqlDataSource1" and runat="server" bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's not something simple like the space between ID="SqlDataSource1" and runat="server" bit.

This would cause the error "Server Tag is not well formed" error.

Comment: Well if you've copied the code directly from your project there is no space inbetween `ID="SqlDataSource1"` and `runat="server"` sections. Your code says `ID="SqlDataSource1"runat="server" ` and it should be `ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"`.

Comment: After giving the space it shows Parser Error Message: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' does not have a public property named 'ConnectionStrings'.

Comment: It needs to say `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SaqibConnectionString %>"`
Which means that the pluralisation of the `ConnectionString` before the equals sign `=` should be removed, and the 's' should be in the `<% %>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Connection string name should be match with what you have given in web config so,

change `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionString:SaqibConnectionString %>"` to

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db %>"
```

or change the name in configuration file which given to your connection string as `SaqibConnectionString`

**Update**:

```
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionString:SaqibConnectionString %>"
                                      /\
                                you missed `s` here
```

You made mistake on Connection String setting, it should be `ConnectionStrings`, note that `s` at the end

try below

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Logid], [Username], [PASSWORD], [Time_Logged_in], [Time_Logged_Out], [Status], [Date_Logged_in], [E_MAIL] from Log_Users"
        UpdateCommand="Update Log_Users SET Logid=@Logid, Username=@Username, PASSWORD=@PASSWORD, Status=@Status, E_mail=@E_mail"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Log_Users WHERE Logid = @Logid" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db %>">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Logid" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Logid" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Username" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PASSWORD" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Status" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="E_MAIL" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: Thanks Alot... this error is solved But Now i am faceing an problem in my sspx.cs file

Answer (score 0):

As seen above your connectionstring name is `db` but you are using `SaqibConnectionString` as connection string.so use `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionString:db %>"` in place of 
`ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionString:SaqibConnectionString %>"`

**Update1**

and your select statement is not right

`SelectCommand="SELECT [Logid], [Username], [PASSWORD], [Time_Logged_in], [Time_Logged_Out], [Status], [Date_Logged_in], [E_MAIL]"`

select statement should be
`select [Logid], [Username], [PASSWORD], [Time_Logged_in], [Time_Logged_Out], [Status], [Date_Logged_in], [E_MAIL] from Log_Users` you are missing `from tablename` in your select statement

**Update2**

you do not have space between `ID="SqlDataSource1"` and `runat="server"`

Comment: actually it shows Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.